# Having errors after updating Firebase pods. <downloadURL> <storageRef>

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Upgraded my Firebase pods and got a ton of errors. I used the Docs on the Firebase Docs webpage so I was able to fix most of them. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Errors:

1. Value of type 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURL'
2. Value of type 'StorageReference' has no member 'put'

Full Code:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseStorage
class HelperService {
    static func uploadDataToServer(data: Data, videoUrl: URL? = nil, ratio: CGFloat, caption: String, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void) {
        if let videoUrl = videoUrl {
            self.uploadVideoToFirebaseStorage(videoUrl: videoUrl, onSuccess: { (videoUrl) in
                uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(data: data, onSuccess: { (thumbnailImageUrl) in
                    sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: thumbnailImageUrl, videoUrl: videoUrl, ratio: ratio, caption: caption, onSuccess: onSuccess)
                })
            })
            //self.senddatatodatabase
        } else {
            uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(data: data) { (photoUrl) in
                self.sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: photoUrl, ratio: ratio, caption: caption, onSuccess: onSuccess)
            }
        }
    }

    static func uploadVideoToFirebaseStorage(videoUrl: URL, onSuccess: @escaping (_ videoUrl: String) -> Void) {
        let videoIdString = NSUUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_ROOF_REF).child("posts").child(videoIdString)
        storageRef.putFile(from: videoUrl, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                ProgressHUD.showError(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
```

Error 1. > if let videoUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {

```
                onSuccess(videoUrl)
            }
        }
    }

    static func uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(data: Data, onSuccess: @escaping (_ imageUrl: String) -> Void) {
        let photoIdString = NSUUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_ROOF_REF).child("posts").child(photoIdString)
```

Error 2. > storageRef.put(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in

```
            if error != nil {
                ProgressHUD.showError(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            if let photoUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {
                onSuccess(photoUrl)
            }

        }
    }

    static func sendDataToDatabase(photoUrl: String, videoUrl: String? = nil, ratio: CGFloat, caption: String, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let newPostId = Api.Post.REF_POSTS.childByAutoId().key
        let newPostReference = Api.Post.REF_POSTS.child(newPostId)

        guard let currentUser = Api.User.CURRENT_USER else {
            return
        }

        let words = caption.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        for var word in words {
            if word.hasPrefix("#") {
                word = word.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters)
                word = word.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.symbols)
                let newHashReference = Api.HashTag.REF_HASHTAG.child(word.lowercased())
                newHashReference.setValue([newPostId: true])
//                let hashTagsRef = DataService.dataService.BASE_REF.child("hashTags").child(postKey)
//                let data = ["to": "", "by": "\(DataService.dataService.currentUserId!)", "hashTag": word.lowercased(), "comment": self.captionTextView.text] as [String : Any]
//                hashTagsRef.setValue(data)
            }
        }

        let currentUserId = currentUser.id
        var dict = ["id": currentUserId! ,"photoUrl": photoUrl, "caption": caption, "likeCount": 0, "ratio": ratio] as [String : Any]
        if let videoUrl = videoUrl {
            dict["videoUrl"] = videoUrl
        }
        newPostReference.setValue(dict, withCompletionBlock: {
            (error, ref) in
            if error != nil {
                ProgressHUD.showError(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            Api.Feed.REF_FEED.child(Api.User.CURRENT_USER!.id!).child(newPostId).setValue(true)

            let myPostRef = Api.MyPosts.REF_MYPOSTS.child(currentUserId!).child(newPostId)
            myPostRef.setValue(true, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                if error != nil {
                    ProgressHUD.showError(error!.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
            })
            ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Success")
            onSuccess()
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ability to get a download URL from upload metadata was removed.  Instead, you can use [`StorageReference.downloadURL()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageReference#downloadurlcompletion)

To upload a file, you have some options, as shown in the [API docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageReference#uploads).  You can see there are variants on `putData` and `putFile`, but no `put`.